# sed doesn't work under cron

Tags: bash, sed, cron

My script:

```
#!/bin/sh
var=$(date)
/usr/bin/sed -i "s|DATE=.*|$(/home/my/script $var)|g" /path/file
```

Running this script manually works **perfectly**. As soon as it is ran from `cron`, in particular the sed portion of the script, will fail.

The variable will hold the correct content under the `cron` environment. Only search/replace fails.

Comment: In what way does the search/replace fail? does it replace things it should not, or not replace things that it should? what is `/home/my/script`?

Comment: The usage of /home/my/script $var provides a single value output that is what sed is replacing in front of DATE=   It doesn't work by removing the entire DATE= line completely. Not something I can replicate manually.

Comment: Well my *guess* is that `/home/my/script` relies on some part of the environment that is present in your interactive shell, but is not present in cron's execution environment. Perhaps redirecting your cron command's output / error streams to a log file will help to troubleshoot it.